RDP Read Only Local Drive
I need an auditor to be able to access the server's file system and be able to run programs on their local computer without the ability to save/copy the data.
At the moment, the best solution we have found is remoteApp:
- Create a remote rdp from windows explorer (Explorer.exe)
- Disable clipboard
- Enable drivestoredirect so that the auditor can access and run their programs from the remote browser session

At the moment it is a semi-working solution, however since drivestoredirect is enabled you can still from the applications save the files to your local system.
The solution might be to set the local disks as read-only, so that you could access your programs but not save anything on them, however, I have not found this option.

You want to be able to access and read from local drives, but not save data to them? That is not an option.

@GregAskew Actually what I need is for the remote client to be able to run a local application using remote files, so that it can write to the remote file system but not to the local one.

Running a local application works. Saving a remote file works. So you only need to prevent modifying local files? Question is unnecessarily convoluted? Why even bring up remoteapp?

@GregAskew Actually the goal is to access a file system (for which there are many other probably better solutions), however it is key that the client does not have the ability to copy data.
